# MessageBox show twice c#

Tags: c#

I don't have any idea why is messagebox appearing twice in exit event
Here's my code:

```
private void dashboard_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult dr = new DialogResult();
        dr = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to close the application?", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
        if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            ConnectionString.conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from user_session_tbl where SESSION_ID = '" + Global_Variables.id + "'", ConnectionString.conn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            ConnectionString.conn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Goodbye " + Global_Variables.fname + " Have a nice Day!", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.None);
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: If this is your main form closing then you don't call Application.Exit.

Comment: You have other problems there. Concatenating string to create sql commands is a very bad practice that could destroy your database. Search about Sql Injection. Also the creation with new of a DialogResult variable is not necessary, just use the one returned by MessageBox.Show and you are good. (To return a DialogResult the MessageBox.Show needs to create it so your initialization is unnecessary)

Comment: As well as the **dangerous** SQL injection problem, you are also caching the connection object, which you should not do. Create a connection, and dispose with `using`, same also for the command object

Comment: thank you very much for your suggestions. I'll use now parameterized query. Thanks again buddy's